# overhead of reserving address space using mmap

Tags: mmap

I have a program that routinely uses massive arrays, where the memory is allocated using `mmap`

Does anyone know the typical overheads of allocating address space in large amounts before the memory is committed, either if allocating with `MAP_NORESERVE` or backing the space with a sparse file? It5 strikes me mmap can't be free since it must make page table entries for the allocated space. I want to have some idea of this overhead before implementing an algorithm I'm considering.

Obviously the answer is going to be platform dependent, im most interested in x64 linux, sparc solaris and sparc linux. I'm thinking that the availability of 1mb pages makes the overhead rather less on a sparc than x64.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the overhead at all. It sounds like [premature optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

Comment: @camelccc the real overhead starts when you access the allocated memory. That is, for treating the resulting interrupt and assigning them physicall memory. Typically around 60µs for 64Kb on current high end systems. You might be interested in Zero Allocation Programming found in High Frequency Trading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead of `mmap` depends on the way you use it. And it is typically negligible when you use it in an appropriate way.

In linux kernel, `mmap` operation can be divided into two parts:

1. look for a free address range that can hold the mapping
2. Create/enlarge vma struct in address space (`mm_struct`)

So allocate large amount of memory use `mmap` do not introduce more
overhead than small ones.

**So you should allocate memory as larger as possible in each time. (avoid mutiple times of small `mmap`)**

**And you may provide the start address explicitly (if possible). This could save some time in kernel in looking for an large enough free space.**

If your application is an multi-threaded program. **You should avoid concurrent calls to `mmap`**. That is because the address space is protected by a reader-writer lock and the mmap always takes the writer lock. `mmap` latency will be orders of magnitude greater in this case.

Moreover, `mmap` only create the mapping but not the page table. Pages are allocated in the page fault handler when being touched. Page fault handler would take the reader lock that protects address space and can also affects `mmap` performance.

**In this case, you should always try to reuse your large array instead of `munmap` it and `mmap` again.** (Avoid pagefaults)