# Does linux carry data structures / abstractions for separate mmap() calls?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, mmap

I want to map a file to memory, using a lot of (thousands) separate `mmap()` calls, because I want to map adjacent (in file) pages to sparse logical addresses:

```
// actual addresses/sizes are page size aligned; 1000/10 for example
mmap(1000, 10, access, flags, file, 0);
mmap(2000, 10, access, flags, file, 10);
mmap(3000, 10, access, flags, file, 20);
...
```

Question: could this cause performance problems or memory overhead, i. e. does linux create some data structures in kernel memory for each `mmap()`-ing, of these calls just update common (per-process) data structures, i. e. number of separate calls doesn't matter.

I don't worry about cost of calls themselves (of cause it's faster to make a single call than thousands), only possible penalty in long run.

Also, is there difference if:

- mmaped file regions are continuous (as in example above)
- logical addresses are continuous, i. e. could linux handle mmaping like

  ```c
  addr = mmap(0, PAGE_SIZE, access, flags, file, 0);
  mmap(addr + PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE, access, flags, file, PAGE_SIZE);
  ```

  as efficiently as

  ```c
  addr = mmap(0, 2 * PAGE_SIZE, access, flags, file, 0);
  ```

I have found an earlier answer to related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16705301/648955 which states that

> Create/**enlarge** (my emphasis) vma struct in address space (mm_struct)

But, on the other hand,

> So you should allocate memory as larger as possible in each time. (avoid mutiple times of small mmap)

-- in **bold**, but doesn't explain the latter statement properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can have many hundred thousands (or perhaps millions) `mmap`-ed segments on Linux running on some ordinary laptop.

My [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) program illustrates that. It repeatedly generates (at runtime) some C code (in some new file) for some function, compiles that into a shared object, then `dlopen` the shared object. I was able to run it up to half a million `.so` (running for about 50 hours); and each call to [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) is doing a few [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

<sup>You could read the code, adapt, then run my `manydl` for a couple of hours, then do `cat /proc/$(pidof manydl)/maps` while it is running.</sup>

Notice that `mmap` is working by *pages* (usually of 4Kbytes each). So you should use it on multiple of 4Kbytes.

I suppose that the kernel is creating some structure for each mmap-ed segment, but it is able to deal with a lot of them. So of course there is some overhead, but I guess it is small enough.

I would suggest having segments of at least a few pages each in average.

So **you can have many** (about half a million at least) of **`mmap`-ed segments** of small (e.g. a dozen kilobytes on average) size, provided they fit together in RAM (you want to avoid [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29)) - e.g. a laptop with 8 or 16Gbytes of RAM.

Comment: Does each `mmap()` create a new segment?

Comment: You don't define what is a segment for you. For me it is (by my definition) the effect of a successful `mmap`; and then indeed there are many segments. You should read the source code and try my `manydl.c`

Comment: Then my definition (a segment is the effect of `mmap`) is compatible with yours. The only non-`mmap`-ed segment are those appearing at `execve` time, and it is well known that `execve` is sort-of `mmap`-ing them

Comment: Read the discussion here http://lwn.net/Articles/598219/. Seems you are trying to do what was done in remap_file_pages().

Comment: @AndyShevchenko seems that 1) many mmap indeed has overhead (separate VMAs) 2) Kernel developers think that my use-case doesnt' exist :(

Comment: @leventov, you may continue that thread. It seems only PyPy project was interested in that stuff in kernel space. And they are quite okay to use as many mmaps as needed.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko ok, now I can answer own question: 1) yes, there are data structures per each `mmap()`, VMAs. But that is probably only serveral dozens of bytes. 2) There is a single segment for all user-mapped memory, though Basile Starynkevitch stated opposite. 3) There is a single page table per process (I was afraid most, that page tables are separate for mappings). 4) VMAs are organized in red-black tree, to find the VMA by address on page fault.